# Microservice design: change on data requirements or schema

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, event-sourcing

Suppose we have 2 services, service A and service B. They are interact with each other with event sourcing. Service A publish event ( entity1 created with fields f1, f2, f3). Service B make own copy of entity1 with fields f1 and f2. Now how we can address this two scenario.

1. New requirement in service 2 and needs for f3. How service2 must update its local data?
2. Schema change on service 1. how service 2 must update its local data and schema?

In scenario 2, services are tightly coupled by schema and can causes errors and this has contradict with event sourcing goal. How can we address this problem?

Comment: If you use a schema format that has well defined evolution rules, such as Avro, then you shouldn't hit any specific issues here as the schemas don't need to directly match

Answer (score 1):

For scenario 1, where the view of the entity changes to incorporate fields which were published to the event stream, the easiest thing is likely to be replaying the events (e.g. if the event stream is on Kafka, using a new consumer group with `auto.offset.reset=earliest`) with an event handler which uses the new field.  This can often be surprisingly quick, allowing you to run this rebuild in a time window where the previous version of the service is running; otherwise, you should be able to run the old instance of service B alongside the new instance (if they're writing to different DBs): when the new instance catches up, you shift whatever traffic is hitting service B to use the new instance and tear down the old (basically a blue-green deploy).

For the second scenario, there are some choices to make:

- You can define an `Entity1CreatedV2` event which fits the new schema (this is likely to require updating consumers to know about the new event first)
- If the fields in the old schema are unchanged (i.e. the schema change is strictly additive), you can keep the old `Entity1Created` message and then have an event for the new fields.  Note that accomodating the schema change for existing entities in service A may drive you to this solution anyway, especially if there's no command-sourcing for service A going on (command-sourcing might allow you to pretend that the new schema was around forever).